# How to get a Sharepoint/OneDrive drive item by path, for an item with a URL-encoded filename

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Suppose I have a file in OneDrive for Business: `/folder1/foo%20.txt`. Note the `%20`, which is a URL-encoded space.

I can get the root of the drive with

```
GET drives/{id}/root
```

I can get the folder with

```
GET drives/{id}/root:/folder1
```

But when I try to get the file with

```
GET drives/{id}/root:/folder1/foo%20.txt
```

I get a 404 error.

If I use `%2520` in the URL (ie, double-encoding the space in the filename), I get the same error. If I use  , I get a 505 error (!).

Is there any way to get the file by path, rather than by using its drive item ID? I'm using the beta Graph API, talking to SharePoint Online/OneDrive for Business. According to [this site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa#invalidcharacters), `%` should be a valid filename character for SharePoint in Microsoft 365.

Comment: Note that if the filename is `foo%2.txt`, then the request succeeds, so it's specifically `%20` that fails

Comment: Is %20 in the file name, or space escaped？

Comment: @Amos the filename is literally `foo%20.txt` with %, 2, 0